# Symfony maker bundle doesn't meet the requirements

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to start a new symfony `--version=5.2` project, and before everything else I'm installing the symfony maker bundle, but I get this error which I can't find no solution for it.

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^1.43 for symfony/maker-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/maker-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/maker-bundle ^1.43 -> satisfiable by symfony/maker-bundle[v1.43.0].
    - symfony/maker-bundle v1.43.0 requires symfony/config ^5.4.7|^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9, v6.0.0, ..., v6.1.0] but the package is fixed to v5.2.12 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require symfony/maker-bundle:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require symfony/maker-bundle:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I tried changing the maker-bundle version myself but still got the same error.
I tried to search for similar problems but no luck finding this error.

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.12",
        "symfony/console": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "docker": false,
            "require": "5.2.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why force the version to 5.2 ? The current Symfony LTS is `5.4` and [Symfony Backward Compatibility Promise][1] is to not have major change in minor version that would break backward compatibility. So in most case you can easily upgrade from 5.2 to 5.4 without changing anything. However, there is a big change with security and authentification, but it should be quite easy to upgrade to the new system by following the documentation.
  [1]: https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/bc.html

Comment: Especially if it is a *new* project. I would go with a version that is actually maintained.

Comment: Can you explain what `before everything else I'm installing the symfony maker bundle` means in this context?  Did you actually start in an empty directory, installed the maker bundle and then tried to install the rest of Symfony?  That would be a bit strange.  Just use the regular symfony CLI to setup your project and the maker bundle will be installed. `symfony new --full --version=5.2 s52project`

Comment: Going with the maintained and current LTS version 5.4 did the job. Problem was my choice of version as you guys mentioned